# Grid show in game in Unity2D

Tags: unity-game-engine, grid

When i press "Play" button in Unity2D i can see "grid" that should be invisible in game.

- I use build in tiledmap option in Unity 2D.
- This "grid" looks like space between tiles, but my tiles is one image 64x64 of 4.
- every block is 32x32 so it's imposible to have spaces between tiles. - I have anti Aliasing disabled (Guy in youtube told that i have to set this if i see "grid" in game)
- My tiles are 32x32 px.

Link to Youtube video i use to learn tilemap: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ryISV_nH8qw

At 6:22 he talk about this "grid bug".

Image of what i see ingame:

[image]
<sub>(source: [zapodaj.net](https://zapodaj.net/images/aeeff185da479.png))</sub>

## Edit

I set the filter mode of image used for tiles to "Point (No Filter)" this help a little, but still i can see the "grid" on the water.

This happen only with the bottom tiles. (zoom to see this)
[image]
<sub>(source: [zapodaj.net](https://zapodaj.net/images/8b54c2eb66eae.png))</sub>

Comment: You should also use the pixel perfect option, as well as disabling anti-aliasing. Check the scaling of your tiles, and rotation of your camera.

Answer (score 0):

put all your assets that go into tilemap into a SpriteAtlas. Also for me thickening the lines by a few pixels after setting rendering of asset to precise and not billinear. This is how i achieved it before!